# how to solve this query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores path of addresses / places each place has a code alias and it's path.

the question is how to translate the path of it's codes into a path of it's name in single query ?

the table looks like this

```
id | code | path        | name
1   011     /100/20/011   Paula Street
34  100     /100          Rekwei
23  20      /100/20       Lengdi
```

the path from above is `100/20/011` and it's should be replaced by it's name `/Rekwie/Lengdi/Paula Street`

anyone can help ?

Comment: I dont understand your data, your expected results, an thus the whole question. Could you please rephrase that a bit, show more data, explain each column, and show the result data you want ?

Comment: @ThomasG Looks like he wants to find all the rows that are prefixes of the given path, and concatenate the names separated by `/`. So `/100`, `/100/20`, and `/100/20/011' are all prefixes of `/100/20/011`, and their corresponding names should be concatenated.

Comment: its clearer now. You should probably use [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php)  to achieve that. It might be simple, depending on how many nested levels you have in your paths : Is 3 the max or can you have a lot more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you append `/%` to each of the parent folder paths, you get a pattern that will match the given path. So you need to find all the rows where that pattern matches, plus the row that exactly matches the full path. Then you concatenate all the names with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SET @path = '/100/20/011';

SELECT CONCAT('/', GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY LENGTH(path) SEPARATOR '/')) as pathname
FROM yourTable
WHERE path = @path OR
(path LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@path, '/', 1), '%')
 AND @path LIKE CONCAT(path, '/%'))
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8iz4zf65eWoHUcNUQy6yei/1)

Make sure you have an index on the `path` column. The `path LIKE ...` check will use that index to reduce the number of rows it has to scan in the `@path LIKE` expression.

Comment: btw I still figure out how to optimize the query to make it faster as the table has million rows

Comment: Did you mean to say you **can't** figure out how to optimize it? The solution to that is probably to redesign your table. I don't think there's any way to optimize it with this structure.

Comment: I've improved the query in a way that should help.